# Practical Implications of DFT Eigenvector Formulations

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, dft, eigendecomposition

Different sets of eigenvectors for the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) are well-established.

Are there any potential practical implications associated with deriving explicit formulations for these DFT eigenvectors? Moreover, is there a specific advantage in identifying a real eigenbasis for the DFT?

Comment: This seems interesting, but what do you mean that "different sets of eigenvectors for the DFT are well established"? Can you spell out what you're getting at a little more or give an example? Looks like an interesting question though.

Comment: DFT has only four distinct eigenvalues: ±1 and ±i. For large matrices (size > 8), each eigenvalue λ yields a multidimensional eigenspace, allowing linear combinations of eigenvectors to create new eigenvectors. Thus, using a basis of DFT's eigenvectors enables the construction of numerous additional eigenvectors.

Comment: @ABB: the answer is quite likely: "no advantage whatsoever". What specific  benefits do you expect and why do you expect them? RBJs answer shows you how to construct and infinite number of Eigenvectors. They are just not particularly useful.

Comment: Dear Hilmar, I am not seeking to create new or simplistic eigenvectors at all. I am well-versed in how one can derive various types of them.

Comment: As you know in order to represent  the eigenvalue decomposition of the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), we must obtain access to all the mutually orthogonal eigenvectors. Once these are identified, the representation takes the form of DFT = $V$diag$V^{t}$. This represents the extent of my knowledge regarding finding eigenvectors. My inquiry pertains to the practical advantages of possessing the columns of $V$ (the eigenvectors of the DFT). How might having explicit formulas for eigenvectors come into play in the field of digital signal processing?

Comment: @ABB: you haven't answered my initial question. Why do you think eigenvectors would be useful in the first place?

Comment: That is indeed my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closed form expression for the eigenvectors would circumvent the need for an eigenvalue decomposition. Existing methods require the eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix that commutes with the DFT or its centered version.

Advantages of knowing the eigenvectors:

(1) In radar (SAR) applications, the angle associated with the DFRFT or the discrete fractional Fourier transform, corresponds or is related to acceleration of a vibrating target. This requires the use of a full basis of orthogonal DFT eigenvectors that resemble discrete Gauss-Hermite functions.

(2) In communications applications, the angle associated with the DFRFT is connected to Doppler effect between Tx and Rx. Again this requires knowledge of the DFT eigenvectors.

Comment: They touch upon some interesting points!

Answer (score 1):

The **unitary** scaling convention for the DFT is identical in scaling with its inverse and preserves energy across the transform or inverse transform:

$$ \begin{align}
\mathcal{DFT}\Big\{x[n]\Big\} & \triangleq X[k] \triangleq \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x[n] \, e^{-j 2\pi kn/N} \\
\mathcal{iDFT}\Big\{X[k]\Big\} & \triangleq x[n] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X[k] \, e^{+j 2\pi kn/N} \\
\end{align} $$

In this answer, I am **not** restricting $0 \le n < N$ nor $0 \le k < N$, they can be any integers because I am pretty much fascistic about the fundamental meaning of the Discrete Fourier Transform: *The DFT and the Discrete Fourier Series are one and the same.  The DFT maps a periodic sequence $x[n]$ with period $N$ to another periodic sequence $X[k]$ also with period $N$ and the iDFT maps it back.*

so
$$ x[n+N] = x[n] \quad\quad \forall \ n \in \mathbb{Z} $$
$$ X[k+N] = X[k] \quad\quad \forall \ k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

With this scaling convention, the Duality theorem:

$$ \mathcal{DFT}\Big\{X[n] \Big\} = x[-k] $$
$$ \mathcal{iDFT}\Big\{x[k] \Big\} = X[-n] $$

We know that, with the DFT, an even-symmetry function

$$ x[n]=x[-n] \qquad \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$

results in an even-symmetry transform

$$ X[k]=X[-k] \qquad \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} $$

And we know that **any** function can be made even-symmetric by adding it to it's reversed image, $x[n]+x[-n]$ is an even-symmetry function.

If you toss all that together, given the definition of the DFT and of $x[n]$ and $X[k]$ above, then we know

$$ \mathcal{DFT}\Big\{x[n]+x[-n]\Big\} = X[k]+X[-k] $$

and from Duality

$$ \mathcal{DFT}\Big\{X[n]+X[-n]\Big\} = x[-k]+x[k] $$

So what do you think the DFT of the sum of all is?

$$ \mathcal{DFT}\Big\{x[n]+x[-n]+X[n]+X[-n]\Big\} = x[k]+x[-k]+X[k]+X[-k] $$

Lookie there, it's an eigenfunction!  I start with an arbitrary $x[n]$ of length $N$, periodically extend it forever, then add it to its flipped version, take the DFT of it, then add that result to the original sum and what you get is an eigenfunction.

There are an infinite number of eigenfunctions for the DFT and they can be constructed methodically.

Comment: You made a valid point, but my inquiry revolves around the advantages of discovering the eigenvectors. To clarify, if we possess a set of eigenvectors from the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), what practical benefits can we derive from this?

Comment: You mean that you're asking: *"What good is an eigenvector?"*

Comment: Focusing solely on the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), if we were to uncover a simple formula for its eigenvectors, what practical benefits could we expect to gain from these eigenvectors?

Comment: I didn't find any practical advantages in the explanation mentioned above as the ANSWER.

Comment: *//"if we were to uncover a simple formula for its eigenvectors,"//* - - - - - - - "if"???